# Inspect code of next line in Python

Tags: python, code-inspection

```
# script.py  

greeting = "hi"
import inspect; import traceback; print traceback.format_stack(inspect.currentframe())[-1]
print greeting
```

The code on the fourth line of the script prints out the file name, line number and the current line:

```
$ python script.py   
File "script.py", line 4, in <module>
    import inspect; import traceback; print traceback.format_stack(inspect.currentframe())[-1]
hi
```

But how can I print out the line number and the content for the next line(`print greeting`) instead of the current one?

This would be convenient for debugging, a oneliner to show the code of the line beneath it.

### Edit

Via Ben's answer I got to this hideous creature:

```
import inspect; import sys; _lne = inspect.currentframe().f_lineno; print "{0}, line {1}:".format(__file__, _lne+1); print open(sys.argv[0]).readlines()[_lne].strip()
```

It's 166 chars long, very verbose. Beware that it raises an `IndexError` when the there is no next line.

Running `python script.py` would print out the following

```
script.py, line 5:  
print greeting
hi
```

I'm hoping some minor change in the original line I posted could lead to the desired behavior, because that included the file name and number without the need of explicitly printing these. And the indentation it provided wasn't unwelcome either.

Comment: In most scenarios knowing the output of the next line is not valuable. This is because your error may reside in calling a class or a function, and seeing the next line only tells you what you *couldn't* get to. You already know this by seeing the line number output. However you can do a try/catch to get more information on your error.

Comment: This is not for those scenarios. It's for when you are using print statements in various files to check the value of different objects. It's more convenient to use an alias that expands into this one liner than to type some identification with the object you want to print via string formatting.

Comment: Glad you clarified. I didn't quite get that from your post. In those cases I always refer to my source, but checking multiple objects at a time is useful indeed.

Answer (score 1):

```
import inspect; import sys ; print open(sys.argv[0]).readlines()[inspect.currentframe().f_lineno].strip()
```

Although this is probably less than useful.

Answer (score 1):

Add a little helper function to lookup and print the relevant filename and line:

```
import inspect, linecache

def show_next(cf):
    'Show the line following the active line in a stackframe'
    filename = cf.f_code.co_filename
    line = cf.f_lineno
    print linecache.getline(filename, line+1)


greeting = "hi"

show_next(inspect.currentframe())
print greeting
```

Of course, if need, it can go into one-line:

```
greeting = "hi"
import inspect, linecache; _f=inspect.currentframe(); print linecache.getline(_f.f_code.co_filename, _f.f_lineno+1)
print greeting
```

Answer (score 1):

The code:

```
# Put format_stack_offset() in a separate module to invoke as needed
def format_stack_offset(frame=None, offset=1):
    from traceback import linecache
    import inspect; 
    if not frame:
        frame = inspect.currentframe().f_back
    lineno = frame.f_lineno + offset
    co = frame.f_code
    filename = co.co_filename
    name = co.co_name
    linecache.checkcache(filename)
    line = linecache.getline(filename, lineno, frame.f_globals)
    retVal =  '\n  File "%s", line %d, in %s' % (filename, lineno, name)
    if line:
        retVal += "\n        " + line.strip()
    return retVal

# script.py
greeting = "hi"
print format_stack_offset()  # This is a one liner to show next line
print greeting
```

Produces

```
 File "/tmp/script.py", line 22, in <module>
    print greeting
 hi
```

Comment: This is too verbose for a one liner.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> from inspect import currentframe, getframeinfo
>
> frameinfo = getframeinfo(currentframe())
>
> print frameinfo.filename, frameinfo.lineno
> ```

Comment: This doesn't print the next line, only the file name and line number. Also, it should be `frameinfo.lineno+3` in your case. (+1 if in one liner)

Comment: print frameinfo.filename, frameinfo.lineno, greeting